# Reasonably quick way to get the full path inside of a scripting dictionary of a key you are accessing?

Tags: vba, dictionary, scripting

Does anyone know a reasonably quick way to get the full path inside of a scripting dictionary of a key you are accessing? An example from a current personal project is looking through a torrent for certain files or paths. With small things like a single torrent file, it's easy to create a treeview and search that and reverse-engineer the path since it is constructed to correspond to the dictionary. However, when loading something like a utorrent resume.dat file of 2000 torrents, it takes forever to create and search a treeview whereas the dictionary can be created and searched almost instantly. However, I would like to be able to reconstruct a treeview (single node path as it would appear if I created the entire tree) of the found data that would correspond to a created full treeview.

I am familiar with Ultima's Bencode Editor project, which is great and I use from time to time but only does part of what I need. He must be accomplishing something similar but is keeping his code private. I pieced together VB6/VBA code which helps me create and manipulate a treeview of that kind of data. However, being VBA/6, it is insanely slow (especially since I need to keep it sorted) and I do not have either the time or probably the skill to port it to a C variant to speed it up and then COM/ActiveX it back so I can use it in Excel 2007 VBA. So what I'm looking for, as an example from a single torrent file, is something that could return me a path like:

/info(0)/files(1)/path(2)

when I have found something ("VIDEO_TS.IFO") from within a structure like

```
info(d)[4]
  files(l)[141]
    Item 1(d)[2]
      length(i)=24576
      path(l)[3]
        Disk1.ep1-9
        VIDEO_TS
        VIDEO_TS.BUP
    Item 2(d)[2]
      length(i)=24576
      path(l)[3]
        Disk1.ep1-9
        VIDEO_TS
        VIDEO_TS.IFO
```

(i.e. if dict.item =   then PathToDictItem(dict.item) = )

Yes, I can keep passing a constructed key as I traverse (search) the dictionary (not quite as simple as it sounds). But my life becomes a whole lot easier if I can simply access the full dictionary path to a key once I've found a value. I'm just hoping someone out there smarter than me knows a relatively simple way I have overlooked to accomplish this.

There were a couple questions similar to this which discussed something called "yield" in python but I am not familiar enough to figure out if they are accomplishing what I want and I don't believe VBA has an equivalent anyway.

Per request of Tim Williams, here is the root of the code which produced the small data example:

```
Private Sub WalkDict(d As Variant, indent As Long)
Dim k, t
For Each k In d.keys
    t = TypeName(d.Item(k))
    Select Case t
        Case "Integer", "Long", "Currency"
            Debug.Print Space(indent * 2); k; "(i)="; Trim(CStr(d.Item(k)))
        Case "String"
            Debug.Print Space(indent * 2); k; "(b)["; Trim(CStr(Len(d.Item(k)))); "]=";
            If Len(d.Item(k)) < 100 Then Debug.Print d.Item(k) Else Debug.Print Left(d.Item(k), 96); " ..."
        Case "Variant()"
            Debug.Print Space(indent * 2); k; "(l)[";
            If IsDimmed(d.Item(k)) Then
                Debug.Print Trim(UBound(d.Item(k)) + 1); "]"
                WalkList d.Item(k), indent + 1
             Else
                Debug.Print "0]"
            End If
        Case "Dictionary"
            Debug.Print Space(indent * 2); k; "(d)["; Trim(UBound(d.Item(k).keys) + 1); "]"
            WalkDict d.Item(k), indent + 1
        Case Else
            Stop 'oops
    End Select

Next
End Sub

Private Sub WalkList(l As Variant, indent As Long)
Dim li, lin, t
For Each li In l
    lin = lin + 1
    t = TypeName(li)
    Select Case t
        Case "Integer", "Long", "Currency"
            Debug.Print Space(indent * 2); li; "(i)="; li.Item(li)
        Case "String"
            Debug.Print Space(indent * 2); li
        Case "Variant()"
            WalkList li, indent + 1
        Case "Dictionary"
            Debug.Print Space(indent * 2); "Item "; Trim(CStr(lin)); "(d)["; Trim(UBound(li.keys) + 1); "]"
            WalkDict li, indent + 1
        Case Else
            Stop 'oops
    End Select
Next
End Sub
```

Just imagine that at any point I'm printing a value that I would be checking that data against criteria and, as I had tried to make clear, if matched, I would like to have the full path through the dictionary/ies to that key/value.

I understand that it is unlikely that VBA makes this readily available and I'm already trying to cobble key-building into the calling. It's just that lists make it more complicated because they don't use the same naming and keys as the rest of the dictionary.

I just know that I am a relatively uninformed hobbyist and there are lots of smart and experienced programmers who wander through these forums and I'm hoping one of them had solved the problem before.

Comment: It's not super-clear from your question what type of data structure you have.  You say dictionary but it looks more like a nested set of dictionaries.  It would also help to be more explicit about haw you're searching your data structure.   Including your code is always a big help.

Comment: I guess I assumed when I mentioned torrents that people would understand that this is bencoded data which usually includes nested dictionaries. I am "walking it" in the traditional sense -- following nesting recursively. The code is tremendously convoluted and poorly written. I will see if I can extract and clean something relevant.

Comment: I think you're going to need to add the path as a parameter in your traversing code - there's no "parent" attribute you can call on a contained item which will give you the containing object/array.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem correctly, I'd probably use Sqlite to store data as I were parsing it and then run a query to get sorted data back to (re)populate the treeview. I believe you can keep Sqlite database in memory and not need to write to disk for performance.

I intended for this to be a comment, but I cannot make a comment.